# How can I reverse the order of columns in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have this simple scenario:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-7">A</div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-5">B</div>
</div>
```

basically if `md`

```
A
B
```

I would like it, if `md`

```
B
A
```

I have tried many variants found on web, like `flex-first` and whatnot.. can't seem to get it to work

Any ideas?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

If you want to change order on `md` and larger sizes you can use `order-md-`, this is provided by [**bootstrap**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#flex-order). It looks like, if you want to change order only on `md` size you will have to define normal order on one larger size [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2315/embedded/#Result)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 order-md-2">A</div>
  <div class="col-md-12 order-md-1">B</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @GM, Have you found the answer?

Answer (score 71):

It's also possible to use the `flex-` helper classes to solve this issue.
This solution allows you to reverse the order without the order count on the columns.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row flex-column-reverse flex-lg-row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-7">A</div>
  <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-5">B</div>
</div>
```

The `flex-direction` is now reversed by default (md) and will be overriden on the lg breakpoint.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I'm working on setting up a website with Japanese, and I was going for a traditional right-to-left layout on larger screens, but then push those columns into rows on smaller width devices (in the other order, so it still reads top-down).

Comment: Should be noted that you can also use  .flex-row-reverse

Comment: +1 should be top answer..it doesn't need you to change anything between the columns instead just modifying a single line..

Comment: For me this breake the responsiviness in bootstrap 5

Comment: The question is tagged bootstrap-4

Answer (score 12):

For Bootstrap v4.1 you can use

```
<div class="row flex-row-reverse">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-7">A</div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-5">B</div>
</div>
```

More information here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#direction

Answer (score 11):

Easiest solution will be:

```
.row{
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
<div class="col-md order-1">First column</div>
<div class="col-md order-md-1">Second column</div>
```

Output on responsive state:

```
Second column
First column
```

Answer (score 4):

I know the question is about Bootstrap 4, but I saw some people asking how to do it in version 5. Here's the example:

```
<div class="col-md-6 order-2 order-md-1">
    <!-- YOUR CODE -->
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 order-1 order-md-2">
    <!-- YOUR CODE -->
</div>
```

ref: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/#order-classes

Answer (score 4):

For Bootstrap 5, the class names have changed to `order-x` where x is the order, i.e. (directly from the docs):

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      First in DOM, no order applied
    </div>
    <div class="col order-5">
      Second in DOM, with a larger order
    </div>
    <div class="col order-1">
      Third in DOM, with an order of 1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See more at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/#reordering