# Bootstrap : How to start class="col", but from the right instead of right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, col

I have this code

```
class="col-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5"
```

I want to make this one, and another but starting from the right side of the container.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5 text-center" style="margin:3px">
        <a class="btn btn-warning">Voir plus de photos</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5 text-center" style="margin:3px">
        <a class="btn btn-success">Commander</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is to keep a space between them in order to not compress themselves on responsivity.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap 4, how reverse the order of columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46672633/bootstrap-4-how-reverse-the-order-of-columns)

Comment: No, this exchange places of the items. I want this order but beginning from the right side, not of the left as it is by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap uses flexbox and build-in some layout alignment within it's grid system.
learn more about it here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment

See example. I added the following class `justify-content-end` to the row:

```
<div class="row justify-content-end">
```

```css
/* To make it more visual */
div {
  padding: 10px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<div class="row justify-content-end">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5 text-center" style="margin:3px">
        <a class="btn btn-warning">Voir plus de photos</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5 text-center" style="margin:3px">
        <a class="btn btn-success">Commander</a>
    </div>
</div>
```